# How do I make my bot respond to non-@ my bot tweets?

Tags: dialogflow-es

It appears that Dialogflow can only respond to what's tweeted at my bot. Is there anyway to get it to respond to non-@ my bot tweets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow's built-in Twitter integration works with @-tweets and DMs.

To handle arbitrary tweets, you would have to write your own Twitter integration using the [Dialogflow API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-agent-setup) and Twitter API, calling the [detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) endpoint for each incoming tweet and posting the response via [Twitter's API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index).